# Двусв'язный список.Краш деструктора

Tags: c++, ооп, list, список, двусвязный-список

Пробую реализовать двусв'язный список,но возникла проблема.Как я понял что деструктор при удалении обьекта крашиться,может кто подсказать в чем причина?
Вот код:

List.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class List{
private:
    template <typename T>
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node* ptrNext;
        Node* ptrPrev;
    };
    int SIZE;
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
public:
    List() :head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {};
    ~List();
    
    int get_size() { return this->SIZE; }

    void push_back(T);
    void pop_front();
    void clear();

    T& operator[](const int);
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"

template <typename T>
List<T>::~List() {
    clear();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {
    while (SIZE) {
        pop_front();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::pop_front() {
    if (SIZE == 0) {
        std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (SIZE == 1) {
        delete head;
        SIZE--;
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *tmp = head;
        head = head->ptrNext;
        delete tmp;
        SIZE--;
    }
}


template <typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T data) {
    Node<T>* tmp = new Node<T>;
    tmp->ptrNext = nullptr;
    tmp->data = data;

    if (head != nullptr) {
        tmp->ptrPrev = tail;
        tail->ptrNext = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    else {
        tmp->ptrNext = nullptr;
        head = tail = tmp;
    }
    SIZE++;
}

template <typename T>
T& List<T>::operator[](const int index) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T>* tl = tail;
    int check = (get_size() - 1) - index;
    if (index < check) {
        Node<T>* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            if (counter == index) {
                return current->data;
            }
            current = current->ptrNext;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    else {
        counter = get_size() - 1;
        Node<T>* current = tail;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            if (counter == index) {
                return current->data;
            }
            current = current->ptrPrev;
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include "List.cpp"

template <typename T>
void print(List<T> lst) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.get_size(); i++) {
        std::cout << lst[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    List<int> lst;
    lst.push_back(5);
    lst.push_back(5);
    lst.push_back(5);
    lst.push_back(5);
    lst.push_back(8);
    lst.push_back(12);
    lst.push_back(36);
    print(lst);
    return 0;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Не уверен, что это единственная ошибка, но забыли написать копирующий конструктор и копирующее присваивание. Читайте про [правило трех](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Можно еще добавить перемещающие операции...

Comment: Не надо `#include "List.cpp"`. Поместите все объявления в заголовок.

Comment: Вы передаёте список в `print` по значению. Создаётся копия списка ссылающаяся на тот же список в памяти. При выходе из `print` копия разрушается, стирая список. Исходный объект ссылается на освобождённую память. Далее про "правило трёх".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да я знаю что так надо,но тут почему-то если я не включу этот файл тогда пишет ссылка на неразрешенный обьект.Что-то в этом роде

Comment: Совсем забыл о конструкторе копирования,искал проблему в деструкторе,спасибо огромное

Comment: Можете пожалуйста в ответ написать как бы выглядел конструктор копирования,я написал но краш остался

Comment: В простейшем случае конструктор копирования должен изготавливать копию всего списка.

Comment: Конкретно здесь (в одном месте) можно передать список по ссылке `print(List<T>& lst) {}`. Но лучше выполнить правило трех и сделать конструктор копирования, в котором нужно заново выделить память под все элементы исходного списка и скопировать данные каждого элемента.

Comment: @DmitryK Тогда уж по константной ссылке.

Comment: ... или можно запретить копирование. Для некоторых типов вполне рабочий вариант.